How to selectively display series in a SpreadsheetGear chart?
I'm working with SpreadsheetGear to generate a line chart in a .NET application. My requirement is to have multiple data series in the chart's dataset but selectively display only certain series on the chart.
I've played around with the SetSourceData()  method changing the references.
I have also tried setting the Format.Line.Visible property to false to hide the series, but this was not the proper solution of setting the selected series for the chart.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

SpreadsheetGear does not yet support filtering out series in a chart.
Hiding a given series' line would be one workaround, though this may not always work well for any number of reasons.  For instance, the charts axis' min / max scale could be affected by outlier values in one of these "hidden" series that would otherwise make it layout differently if the series were truly filtered out.  Or, if you display the chart legend, you'll still see an entry for this series there.
Alternatively, you'll most likely need to be explicit about what series you want added to the chart.  IChart.SetSourceData(...) expects a contiguous range of cells.  Since "filtering" series will almost certainly create a non-contiguous range for your chart source data, you'll need to use the IChart.SeriesCollection.Add() method to add individual series to a chart.  Below is a simple hard-coded example demonstrating how you could skip over values in Column C but create series for the data in Columns A, B and D:
using SpreadsheetGear;
using SpreadsheetGear.Charts;

...

// Set chart series for data in Columns A, B, and D (skipping C)
ISeries series1 = chart.SeriesCollection.Add();
series1.XValues = "A1:B1,D1";
series1.Values = "A2:A4";

ISeries series2 = chart.SeriesCollection.Add();
series2.Values = "B2:B4";

ISeries series3 = chart.SeriesCollection.Add();
series3.Values = "D2:D4";

